# Has there only ever been one Lucille?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Lucille is Negan's signature weapon, but ultimately only a wooden bat. Considering that Negan has put Lucille to good use over the story, I'm surprised that it remains in such good shape.

Has there only ever been one single Lucille, or has Negan replaced Lucille over time?

Comment: Are you talking about the show or the books ?

Comment: It depends on the wood used. Nowadays people are using light wood for a faster swing, so the bat is more prone to break. Yet, old classic bats, are really really really hard to break. They probably won't break with a skull, or 100. Not to mention walking dead's skulls are probably brittle, judging by the ease with which they bludgeon them.

Neegan also seems like a story-teller. If he had a previous bat, he'd probably call it something else, and he'd use up the chance to talk about this past romance that he broke off. EDIT:I just realized I might be walking into a comic spoiler minefield.

Comment: _This is my Lucille. There are many like it, but this one is mine._

Comment: I guess you're not talking about [this lucille.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucille_(guitar))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no evidence that there have been more than one Lucille, but there is evidence that suggests that because of Negan's affection for Lucille, she is one of a kind.

Since you don't mention if you're asking from the TV show or comics perspective, the rest of my answer contains spoilers for the comics, and potential future events/revelations in the show:

> Originally, of course, there was another Lucille, as revealed in the miniseries "Here's Negan": Negan's wife, whom he named his bat after. Since he named his weapon after his deceased wife, he probably feels affection for it, and replacing it would not come easy to him. This is supported by several events in the comics. In volume 19 (issue 113), Carl shoots Lucille and Negan becomes furious. In volume 27 (issue 159), Lucille is destroyed in battle, and Negan is devastated.

Comment: I meant comics.